# How to debug the ArrayList constructor with initialCapacity

Tags: java, debugging, arraylist, collections

When I read the `ArrayList` code, I tried to debug the constructor

```java
public ArrayList() {
    this.elementData = DEFAULTCAPACITY_EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA;
}
```

but it is never invoked，it invokes

```java
public ArrayList(int initialCapacity) {
    if (initialCapacity > 0) {
        this.elementData = new Object[initialCapacity];
    } else if (initialCapacity == 0) {
        this.elementData = EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal Capacity: "+initialCapacity);
    }
}
```

and the `initialCapacity` is `=1` forever, whatever I set.

I just want to invoke other constructor.

Comment: How are you instantiating your ArrayList?

Comment: What is “it”? Include “it” in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you instantiate your ArrayList as such:

ArrayList list = new ArrayList<>();

And debug this code it will invoke:

[IntelliJ debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WB7o.png)

as desired

Comment: well...It does'n work....

Comment: ArrayList list = new ArrayList<>(); and ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<>(); all invoke the initalCapacity = 1 construct funcktion

Comment: When you say "initialCapacity = 1", what do you mean exactly? The only way initial capacity could be 1 is if you pass in 1 as an argument. If you place a break point inside that method and it hits it with initialValue = 1, look at the thread stack and see if somehow some other method is being invoked which calls new ArrayList<>(1);

Comment: Also, this is only the initial capacity of the list. When you call ArrayList.add(), it checks to see if the size has been reached and if it has, it will increase it...